# How to get all Facebook check-ins for a specific page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a Facebook-Page which is also a place in FB, so users can check-in to that place (for example with an iPhone). Now I want to get all the checked-in users from my page. But I always get an empty array, even when several users are checked-in. I'm using the following URI from the Graph-API:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/checkins?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

For the access-token I've created an FB-app and assigned the permissions manage_pages, offline_access, user_checkins and friends_checkins.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am also looking exactly into this. Did you get any solution?

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm still looking for it...

Comment: Checkin connection returns only checkins made to this Place Page by the current user, and friends of the current user.

Comment: Hi Larry.  Can you explain how you produce an access token from your FB app please?

Comment: Anyone found a way to retrieve all the checkins for a page? I can only retrieve checkins by me and my friends.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the page access token (see Page Login on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

You can get the page access token by querying `me/accounts` using the user access token.

In that list of accounts returned will be the page access token.

You can play around with it here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly.  I was having a similar problem, and found this bug report a few months back.  It is now fixed.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165533086912181

Since this has been fixed, it should work for you now.  If not, you may want to try FQL.  You can access it through the graph API by accessing

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+checkins+FROM+pages+WHERE+page_id=WHATEVER.

Comment: Actually the query might be something like this: 'SELECT author_uid, page_id FROM checkin WHERE page_id = APPID'. Anyways, I can only retrieve the list of checkins made by me and my friends.

Comment: **fql** is outdated !