# List all who has checked in on page?

Tags: facebook, checkin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all Facebook check-ins for a specific page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058798/how-to-get-all-facebook-check-ins-for-a-specific-page)

Is there a way to list everyone who has checked in to my page? And not just my friends.

I've done a standard app with:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/checkins?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]`

The app works very well but I'm only seeing my checkin friends. I'm admin of the page and it would be great to see everyone who has made a checkin. Any thoughts? Thanks!